# Changing Variable by using variable+string? LUA

Tags: lua

I have a script where I have many variables for different guns. There are

```
UMP45Ammo = false
UMP45Fov = false

AKMAmmo = false
AKMFov = false
```

etc I got like 12 guns and more variables

Then I have a global variable called `cgun`

My problem is when a button is clicked I wanna change the value of selected guns specific property(like **ammo** to `true`)

So I tried something like
`cgun+Ammo = true` and I tried even making new local variable

```
mgun1 = cgun+Ammo 
mgun1 = true
```

etc. How can I do this or is it impossible?

Comment: Have you looked into [tables](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html)?

Comment: Can you simplify how tables work with this since I cannot seem to see how it works.Thanks!

Comment: It allows you to access variables by string.

Comment: [Read the manual](https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) (or at least try reading it before asking the internet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be better to use objects to describe the guns. Then it's easy to change a gun property of the current gun.

```
-- gun list
UMP45 = {Ammo = false, Fov = false}
AKMA = {Ammo = false, Fov = false}

cgun = UMP45  -- set current gun
print(cgun.Ammo)

cgun.Ammo = true -- set Ammo of current gun
print(cgun.Ammo)
```

Comment: Will try ill come say if it works gotta edit the script alot to make that work

Comment: Worked Thank you Mike67!

Comment: Please confirm this answer to get the post off the "No answer" list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to access global memory using the _G variable. It works, but it's ugly in this case:

```
_G[cgun.."Ammo"] = 0
```

Note that if cgun is a reference you have to change it to a string, either using debug.getlocal or using a simple search:

```
 for k, v in pairs(_G) do if v == cgun then _G[k.."Ammo"] = 0 break end
```

Again this is not a very good solution. Generally speaking, you don't want to pollute the global space _G with a lot of variables.

Just store a reference to your current gun as Mike suggested.

```
currentGun = { ammo = 10, name = "AK47" }
```

Comment: this answer is utter non-sense. why would iterate over _G? and what is `_G[cgun+"Ammo"]` ? it will cause a Lua error for attempting to add string to whatever cgun is

Comment: @Piglet It does make sense; the whole second code block addresses the `cgun` not being a string part. It's ugly, but 2dengine acknowledged that already. It's an example to illustrate how the global environment works and it might be a reasonable aproach when you can't control how variables are stored.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I can't follow you. no matter what `cgun` is, `cgun+"Ammo"` will cause an error and so does `k+"Ammo"`  am I missing something here?

Comment: `cgun+"Ammo"` will work if cgun is a string where `AK47 = true AK47Ammo = 10` and `cgun = "AK74"` (see original question). If cgun is a reference such as `AK47 = {} cgun = AK47` then you need to resolve it to a string - hence the iteration. I tried to answer the original question of whether `cgun+"Ammo"` could work. Yes, it could work, but it's not a good solution.

Comment: String concatenation in Lua is "..", not the plus sign. The only other thing the "+" operator works for is tables with defined metatable methods.